# Qual é a finalidade do módulo em Elixir?

Tags: característica-linguagem, elixir

Estou estudando Elixir e me deparei com a palavra chave `defmodulo`, usei para definir um módulo básico que exibi uma mensagem:

```
defmodule Mensagem do    
    def escreve(msg) do
        IO.puts msg
    end    
end
```

Chamando da seguinte forma:

```
Mensagem.escreve("Oie amigo do gato :D")
```

Saída:

> Oie amigo do gato :D

A forma como o módulo é definido me lembrou muito uma classe.

## Dúvidas

- Qual a finalidade do módulo em Elixir?
- Um modulo é a mesma coisa que uma classe?
- Pode haver instancia dele para representar um objeto?

Comment: Me parece que os módulos neste caso não terão instancias, não serão objetos, os módulos estão mais proximos aos namespaces, como se fosse funções dentro de namespace no PHP, ou defs dentro de escopos (módulos também) em Python, na verdade do Elixir lembrou-me bastante como é no Python e em Ruby, os módulos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual a finalidade do módulo em Elixir?

Basicamente [agrupar funções que estão relacionadas e criar um escopo para seu uso](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html), assim as funções dentro dele só podem ser acessados através do nome dele.

> Um modulo é a mesma coisa que uma classe?

Não exatamente, mas já que o AP sabe C# posso comprar. É como uma classe estática dessa linguagem, que não é uma classe como se conhece. O módulo tem muitas limitações para estabelecer que é realmente uma classe, foi usado um termo já existente em C#, mas ele é errado, o VB.NET também chama o mesmo mecanismo de [`Module`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement).

Ele está mais para um *namespace*, apesar de ter algumas semânticas diferentes.

> Pode haver instancia dele para representar um objeto?

Não, essa é a limitação mais óbvia.